# What is the best way to upload multiple images in aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, multifile-uploader

i am creating a website and users can upload maximum 15 images. I store images and resized images(with aws lambda function) in aws s3, but if i send images to aws s3 one by one it will be too expensive for aws s3 bill. Should i zip them in a folder and send to aws s3, after that unzip them and resize them in aws? thanks for answers.

I am using react-springboot.

Comment: Why do you say that "it will be too expensive for aws s3 bill"? The cost of a PUT request is `$0.0055 per 1000 requests`. So, if you were to send 1 million objects, the requests would cost $5.50. Is that too much to pay for 1 million PUT requests?

Answer (score 0):

Storing in zip will help you reduce the per request cost for s3 and a little space (since zip files may not affect much to images, depending on the zip compression used).

For every user upload example(approx. cost as per AWS site):

Not Storing: $0.000005 per put request X 15 + $0.000004 per Get request X 15

Storing as ZIP: $0.000005 X 1 + 0.000004 X 1

Other options include why not resize the images in Lamda (Async call) and then directly store to AWS S3. This depends on the time your function takes which will incur you additional cost.

Comment: For get method, i will use resized images, so when i put zip folder in s3 i have to unzip and resize them. But i think aws doesnt compress files, so i should send images one by one?

Comment: yes you will need to unzip and compress them manually. Send images one by one post processing.